# React get value from HandleInputChange function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have function like that :

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      web3 : '',
      address: '',
      InputAmount: '',
    }

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

handleInputChange(e) {
  this.setState({InputAmount: e.target.value*this.state.weiConversion});
}
```

When I try to get data from my input to send it in my component "Comp1", the value is always **NaN** why ?

```
        <h5 value={this.state.InputAmount}></h5>
        <input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={this.handleInputChange} required pattern="[0-9]*[.,][0-9]*"/>
        <Comp1 input={this.state.InputAmount}></Pool1>
```

Comment: Take into account that you have to handle when the InputAmount value is an empty string "", also remember that the e.target.value is a string, so you should parse it to integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just parse the value to integer because it is a string

```
this.setState({InputAmount: +e.target.value*this.state.weiConversion});
```

Comment: if I understand : `const input = parseInt(this.setState({InputAmount: +e.target.value*this.state.weiConversion}))` ?

Comment: no need for parseInt function just add + before it and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Please note that, your input is of type `text`, and in javascript, even though you multiply `string * string` provided their parsed value is `Number`, it will always result in integer output. eg: `'2' * '2' => 4`. But in your case, if you want only numerical value, you can go ahead with `type="number"`.

and `this.state.weiConversion` as long as stays an integer value, you will get your desired output.

```
eg: '2' * 1234 => 2468
    '22' * '1' => 22
    '2@;' * 4 => NAN
```

Please make sure `this.state.weiConversion` doesn't contain special characters, even though it is a string. you don't want any special characters in arithmetic operation.